# Caching tables in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark SQL and would like to cache a table that was originally created in Hive.  This works fine if the table is in Hive's default database, e.g.

```
CACHE TABLE test1;
```

However, if it is in a different database, e.g. `myDB` then I cannot do

```
CACHE TABLE myDB.test1;
```

since Spark complains that ``` failure: ``as'' expected but ```.' found`.

I can however access and query the table, for instance by running

```
SELECT * FROM myDB.test1;
```

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer:

```
USE myDB;
CACHE TABLE test1;
```